# How to pass a parameter to vbscript?

Tags: cmd, vbscript

I have a vbs that runs several tor connections:

```
proxycount = 3
countries = ""

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set f = FSO.OpenTextFile("proxyList.txt", 2, True) 

For i=0 To proxycount-1 Step 1

    Port = 9000 + i
    CPort = 8000 + i

    If Not (countries = "") Then
            countries = " -ExitNodes " & countries
    End If

    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run "data\tor.exe -f data\torrc -SocksPort " & Port & " -ControlPort " & CPort & " -DataDirectory data\torf" & i & countries, 0
    WshShell = Null
    f.WriteLine "127.0.0.1:" & Port 

Next

f.Close
```

And it works great, but when I'm trying to pass on proxycount as a parameter:
[CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPiQc.png)
it stops working:

```
countries = ""

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set f = FSO.OpenTextFile("proxyList.txt", 2, True) 

For i=0 To WScript.Arguments(0)-1 Step 1

    Port = 9000 + i
    CPort = 8000 + i

    If Not (countries = "") Then
            countries = " -ExitNodes " & countries
    End If

    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run "data\tor.exe -f data\torrc -SocksPort " & Port & " -ControlPort " & CPort & " -DataDirectory data\torf" & i & countries, 0
    WshShell = Null
    f.WriteLine "127.0.0.1:" & Port 

Next

f.Close
```

with error "string 17, symbol 2. Can't find a file" in this line:

```
WshShell.Run "data\tor.exe -f data\torrc -SocksPort " & Port & " -ControlPort " & CPort & " -DataDirectory data\torf" & i & countries, 0
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't know where the error is.

Comment: How do you pass the parameter? If it is a numerical value I believe this should work. It would not work if you pass it as say `-10` (with the dash). Also, the line `WshShell = Null` does not what you want I think, should probably be `Set WshShell = Nothing`

Comment: @Arno van Boven, it is a numerical value "launch.vbs 2". I added the screenshot in the post.

Comment: It would help if you also included the error you are getting

Comment: @Arno van Boven, string 17, symbol 2. Can't find a file.

Comment: I don't immediately spot a difference. You'd expect a file with a 0 and a 1 if you pass 2 as the argument. (and 0, 1 and 2 in the hardcoded example). Check if you can find a difference in the generated filenames when using the different methods.

Comment: Try passing  the full path of the exe instead of just `data\tor.exe`. Similarly for the other paths.

Comment: @Arno van Boven, The real error is not in the 17 line. This line is the same in bought examples. But the first one works, the second does not. All I want to do is just replace proxycount with first argument WScript.Arguments(0).

Comment: @Jooms in which case show us the command line you use to run the script, should be something like `cscript.exe yourscript.vbs 3` *(assume running from the working directory)*.

Comment: @ArnovanBoven you're right, but it doesn't matter as it get's overwritten by `Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` in each iteration of the loop. Should have a final `Set WshShell = Nothing` outside the loop but VBScript is pretty good when it comes to clean up of objects when the script ends. But as you say `WshShell = Null` might cause some unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Lankymart, https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPiQc.png This cmd command works without an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this line in the beginning fixed the problem:

```
WshShell.CurrentDirectory = FSO.GetParentFolderName(WSH.ScriptFullName)
```